# Learning managed C++ generics

Tags: .net, generics, c++-cli, binary-search-tree

I created a small BST project in managed C++ for school.  Worked well, but now I'm trying to figure out how to do the same project using generics (first project used int).  For the life of me I cannot see what I'm fundamentally screwing up.  Hoping for direction.

GenericNodeClass.h:

```
/*
GenericNodeClass.h.  Created by Ed Thompson for IS375, C++ Intermediate, City University
of Seattle.

GenericNodeClass.h provides for members for creation of a generic binary tree

*/

#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

generic <typename T> where T : IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
ref class Node
{
public:
T data;
T parent;
Node<T> ^ left;
Node<T> ^ right;

// Constructor that takes one parameter:
// a T, representing the value of a new node
Node(T n) 
{
    data = n;
}
};
```

BinarySearchTreeClass.h

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <climits>
#include "GenericNodeClass.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

generic <typename T> where T : IComparable<T> , IEquatable<T>
ref class BinarySearchTreeClass

{
public:

Node<T>^ rootNode;
T _p;

// constructors
// default
BinarySearchTreeClass(){}

BinarySearchTreeClass(T t)
{
    // create a new Node in the Binary Search Tree 
    rootNode = gcnew Node<T> (t);
}

// method to return a node if it exists in the tree
// takes two parameters:  an instance of the Node class, and a
// value representing the value of the node to be looked up 
Node<T> ^ lookUp(Node<T> ^node, T key)
{
    if(node == nullptr)
        return node;
    if(node->data == key) 
        return node;
    else
    {
        if (node->data->CompareTo(key) < 0)
            return lookUp(node->right, key);
        else
            return lookUp(node->left, key);
    }
}

// method to create new node.  Method takes two parameters:
// a parameter of the value for the node data, and a value
// for the node's parent.
Node<T> ^newNode(T key, T parent)
    {
        Node<T> ^node = gcnew Node<T>(key);
        node->data = key;
        node->left = nullptr;
        node->right = nullptr;
        node->parent = parent;

        return node;
    }

// insertNode method inserts a new node into an existing 
// Binary Search Tree.  This method takes two parameters:
// an instance of Node<T> (node), and a value of T, 
// representing the value of the node being inserted
Node<T> ^insertNode(Node<T> ^node, T input)
{
    Node<T> ^returnNode;

    if (node != nullptr)
        _p = node->data;

    // if the node is non-existant, create a new node
    // with the value of the parameter 'input' and the 
    // value of the new node's parent (_p).
    if (node == nullptr)
    {
        // pass class variable _p to set value
        // of the new node's parent value.
        returnNode = newNode(input, _p);
        return returnNode;
    }

    // if the input parameter value is less than 
    // or equal to the node value, insert node using 
    // the left hand node leaf of the current node 
    // as starting point
    if (input->CompareTo(node->data) < 0)
    {
        // set variable p to value of node->data value (this
        // will be the parent of the new node)
        _p = node->data;
        node->left = insertNode(node->left, input);
    }

    // if the input parameter value is greater than 
    // the node value, insert node using the right hand
    // node leaf of the current node as starting point
    else
    {
        _p = node->data;
        node->right = insertNode(node->right, input);
    }
    return node;
}

// method to find the left most node in a Binary Search Tree
// takes an instance of Node<T> as parameter
Node<T> ^leftMost(Node<T> ^node)
{
    if (node == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    while (node->left != nullptr)
        node = leftMost(node->left);
    return node;
}

// method of return the right most node in a Binary Search Tree
// takes an instance of Node<T> as parameter
Node<T> ^rightMost(Node<T> ^node)
{
    if (node == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    while (node->right != nullptr)
        node = rightMost(node->right);
    return node;
}

// method to return the size of a Binary Tree
// takes an instance of Node<T> as parameter
int treeSize(Node<T> ^node)
{
    if(node == nullptr || node->left == nullptr && node->right == nullptr)
        return 0;

    else
        return treeSize(node->left) + 1 + treeSize(node->right);
}

// method that prints to console the value of each node from lowest to highest
// takes an instance of Node<T> as parameter
void printTreeInOrder(Node<T> ^node)
{
    if (node != nullptr)
    {
        printTreeInOrder(node->left);
        Console::WriteLine(node->data);
        printTreeInOrder(node->right);
    }
}

// method that prints to console a graphic representation of a binary tree
// takes an instance of Node<T> as parameter
void printGraphicRepresentation(Node<T> ^node)
{
    // the width of the tree is the max height /2 (?)
    // need to know how wide the tree is
    // At treeWidth / 2, print node 
    // on new line, at nodePosition - 1, if node has a left, print a "/"
    // on same line, at nodePosition + 1, if node has a right, print a "\"
}

// method that prints to console all members of a given node
// takes an instance of Node<T> as parameter
void printNodeMembers(Node<T> ^node)
{
    Console::WriteLine("Members of Node " + node->data + " include: ");
    if (node->parent != nullptr)
        Console::WriteLine("Parent: " + node->parent);
    else
        Console::WriteLine("This node has no parent.");
    if (node->left != nullptr)
        Console::WriteLine("Left-member: " + node->left->data);
    else
        Console::WriteLine("This node has no left-member.");
    if (node->right != nullptr)
     Console::WriteLine("Right-Member: " + node->right->data);
    else
        Console::WriteLine("This node has no right-member.");

}
};
```

TestClass.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "GenericNodeClass.h"
#include "BinarySearchTreeClass.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

int main ()
{
BinarySearchTreeClass<int>^ BTree = gcnew BinarySearchTreeClass<int>();

// instantiate new Node instance with starter value
Node<int> ^rootNode = gcnew Node<int>(5);

// insert additional nodes
BTree->insertNode(rootNode, 3); 
BTree->insertNode(rootNode, 7);
BTree->insertNode(rootNode, 4);
BTree->insertNode(rootNode, 6);
BTree->insertNode(rootNode, 2);
BTree->insertNode(rootNode, 9);
BTree->insertNode(rootNode, 1);
BTree->insertNode(rootNode, 8);
BTree->insertNode(rootNode, 0);
BTree->insertNode(rootNode, 10);
BTree->insertNode(rootNode, 12);
BTree->insertNode(rootNode, 11);
Console::WriteLine("The value of the left-most node in this tree is: " + BTree->leftMost(rootNode)->data); 
Console::WriteLine("The value of the right-most node in this tree is: " + BTree->rightMost(rootNode)->data);
Console::WriteLine("The size of this Binary Search Tree is: " + BTree->treeSize(rootNode));
Console::WriteLine("Printing Binary Search Tree in order: ");
BTree->printTreeInOrder(rootNode);

// TO EXAMINE THE PROPERTIES OF A GIVEN NODE, CHANGE THE SECOND PARAMETER OF 
// THE lookUp METHOD IN THE FOLLOWING LINE OF CODE TO THE NODE DESIRED TO BE EXAMINED
BTree->printNodeMembers(BTree->lookUp(rootNode, 7));
Console::WriteLine();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are badly mixing up both the syntax and semantics of .NET generics with native C++ templates.  Talk to your teacher, this is almost certainly not what you should be doing.

Comment: Well, I've got the error list down to the edited list above by fixing the mistake on instantiation of the Node<T> class to the above from "Node<T> newNode = gcnew Node<T>(5)" duh, and by adding the condition  where T : IComparable , IEquatable<T> to the Node Class and BinarySearchTree class.  It looks like the only problem I'm still having is to deal with the <= operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison operators are not available for use with generics. There's no interface that defines them, and unlike C++ templates, the compiler doesn't know all the types that will be used.

The thing you want is `IComparable<T>`. This interface defines the method `CompareTo(T)`, which will return a negative number, zero, or a positive number if the first object is less than, equal to, or greater than the other one, respectively. (That can be a little hard to remember, so remember this: `(x [symbol] y)` turns into `(x.CompareTo(y) [symbol] 0)`.)

Given a general type `T`, you don't know whether `T` actually implements `IComparable<T>` or not. What you want to do is force the compiler to only allow classes that implement `IComparable<T>`.

```
generic <typename T> where T : IComparable<T> ref class Node { ... };
generic <typename T> where T : IComparable<T> ref class BinarySearchTreeClass { ... };
```

Now you can use the `CompareTo` method in your class:

```
if (node->data->CompareTo(key) < 0)
    return lookUp(node->right, key);
else
    return lookUp(node->left, key);
```

A couple other minor syntax issues:

`generic <typename T> ref class Node<T>`: Don't need `Node<T>`, just `Node`. The Node class is generic already because of the `generic <typename T>`, you don't need the `<T>` as well.

`Node<T>(){}`: You don't need the `<T>`. The constructor of a generic class is already generic, you don't need to specify it again.

Comment: Edited original code samples above to reflect changes for anyone looking for a very basic example of a generic Binary Search Tree in managed C++.  Works like a champ.